# MYSQL fetch 10 posts, each w/ vote count, sorted by vote count, limited by where clause on posts

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, aggregate-functions

I want to fetch a set of Posts w/ vote count listed, sorted by vote count (e.g.)

```
Post 1 - Post Body blah blah - Votes: 500
Post 2 - Post Body blah blah - Votes: 400
Post 3 - Post Body blah blah - Votes: 300
Post 4 - Post Body blah blah - Votes: 200
```

I have 2 tables:

**Posts** - columns - `id`, `body`, `is_hidden`
**Votes** - columns - `id`, `post_id`, `vote_type_id`

Here is the query I've tried:

```
SELECT p.*, v.yes_count
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT post_id, vote_type_id, COUNT(1) AS yes_count
    FROM votes 
    WHERE (vote_type_id = 1) 
    GROUP BY post_id
    ORDER BY yes_count DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10) v 
ON v.post_id = p.id
WHERE (p.is_hidden = 0)
ORDER BY yes_count DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

**Correctness:** The above query *almost works*. The subselect is including `votes` for `posts` that have `is_hidden = 1`, so when I left join it to `posts`, if a hidden post is in the top 10 (ranked by votes), I can end up with records with NULL on the `yes_count` field.

**Performance:** I have ~50k posts and ~500k votes. On my dev machine, the above query is running in .4sec. I'd like to stay at or below this execution time.

**Indexes:** I have an index on the Votes table that covers the fields: `vote_type_id` and `post_id`

**EXPLAIN**

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY  p  ALL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  45985  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  10   
2  DERIVED  votes  ref  VotingPost  VotingPost  4     319881  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT p.*, count(*) yes_count
FROM posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v ON (v.post_id = p.id and v.vote_type_id = 1)
WHERE p.is_hidden = 0
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY yes_count DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Since this is mysql, group by only p.id s will work (but this won't be portable to other dbs)

Comment: this is correct, but it is taking 1 second to execute. i am thinking about storing the vote count in each post record..

Comment: try adding an index on vote_type_id.post_id.  That should speed it up.